# Filter images in loading new page with Click event in casperjs?

Tags: filter, casperjs, slimerjs

I'm using latest version of `casperjs` and `slimerjs` in windows 10.
I create a casper instance as the following:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    colorizerType: 'Dummy',
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  false,
        loadPlugins: false
    }
});
casper.on('resource.requested', function(requestData, networkRequest) {
    if (requestData == null || requestData.headers == null || requestData.url == null || requestData.url == '') return;
    var requestedFileUrl = requestData.url;
    if (/http:\/\/.+?\.css/img.test(requestedFileUrl) ||
        /cdn/img.test(requestedFileUrl) ||
        /Content/img.test(requestedFileUrl) ||
        /File/img.test(requestedFileUrl) ||
        /bundle/img.test(requestedFileUrl) ||
        /font/img.test(requestedFileUrl) ||
        /css/img.test(requestedFileUrl))
    {
        networkRequest.abort();
    }
});
```

It's OK and not loads images and fonts and ... if I use the following code:

```
casper.start(url);
```

But if I click on an element in page, it loads all images in new page:

```
casper.then(function() {
    casper.click('[click-on-me]');
});
```

How can we filter images in click event in casperjs?

Comment: Try `--load-images=false` to load none images...

Comment: `unknown option --load-images=false` if I use this parameter

Comment: Reading from the [source](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/blob/master/bin/casperjs) of newest `casperjs`, it should be worked... Try `casperjs --load-images=false my_casperjs_script.js`.

Comment: As you can see in question, I'm using `slimerjs`, So probably it doesn't work with `slimerjs`.

Comment: My knowledge about `slimerjs` is very limited... So you may post a github issue to ask about that...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I have to use `--load-images=false` as the following for `slimerjs`:

```
-load-images false
```